# I want to "clone" google calendar's interface with c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, calendar

What would you recommend me to do in order to accomplish that?
I'm developing a Scheduling software and i love google's interface (view in day, week, month) but i'm thinking in doing everything from ground zero. Is there a way to use pre-created controls or something much more easy than my idea ?
Thank you all.

It's for web with asp.net and c#. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford Telerik or DevExpress controls (or similar component suites), it's a much faster way.

However, if you want to try a free (LGPL) one, have a look here:

http://bettercalendar.codeplex.com/

Comment: I really like this approach but i need it for web. i'm sorry i didn't point that out.

Comment: The link to the free one is for windows, but Telerik, like Robert mentioned (and probably DevExpress) has a good calendar for asp.net:  http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx.  Unfortunately, they do cost though.

Comment: i was awared of that package and i think it's great but unfourtenately i can't afford that i'm just starting in the business world. Thank you for your help if you know of something free please tell me. Have a good day.

Comment: @rolando - Full calendar is free

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if you're talking about a desktop application or a web application.  The link above will help for desktop software, if you're after web controls, try http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ which is built on jQuery.

Comment: Nice piece of jQuery.  I have been looking for something like this myself.